# Taylor series expansion and Laplace transform final value theorem

Tags: asymptotics, taylor-expansion, laplace-transform

I cant figure out how some transformations are made in one article on physics. Here is expression in s-domain and they want to find its asymptotic value.
$$ \xi(s) = \nu_1(s+1)=\frac{1}{(s+1)} (1+\frac{2h(s+1)}{1-2g(s+1)}) (*) $$
Here is quote from the text: 
Asymptotic value may be obtained from equation $(*)$ by application of Laplace transform final value theorem. If the functions $(s+2)h(s+1)$ and $(s+2)(1-2g(s+2))$ (???) are expanded in Taylor series around s=0 retaining only first power terms. Using abbreviations:
$$ g_2=dg/ds|_{s=1} $$
$$ h_1=2h(1) $$
$$ h_2=-d(2^{2-s}h(s))/ds|_{s=1} $$
we can get
$$ \xi^{\infty}_1=\frac{g_1}{h_2} $$
$$ \Delta \xi^{\infty}=\frac{g_2}{h_2}-(ln2 - \frac{1}{2})\xi^{\infty}_1 -1$$
final value can be written as 
$$ \lim_{u \to \infty} \xi_1(u)= \xi^{\infty}_1-\Delta \xi^{\infty}e^{-u} $$ 
So, apparently the want to expand enumerator and denominator of (*) in Taylor series separetly (are they ? im terribly confused). And then apply final value theorem like:
$$ \lim_{s \to 0} s\xi(s) $$ 
I'm trying to do it and cant get anything similar to their answer. Could anyone please help me ?
also it is known that $h(0)=1/2; g(1)=1/2; g(1)=1$.

Comment: This is pretty hard to parse, for me.  Could you give the name and authors of the article?

Comment: Sure. M. T. Robinson The influnce of the scattering law on the radiation damage displacement cascade. 1965 Philosophical Magazine.

Comment: @Antonio i'm sorry for bothering you, but is there a chance for a help ?

Comment: I wasn't able to find a version of the paper online that my university had access to.  Do you know if it's freely available somewhere?

Comment: i doubt it, but i can send it to you by mail.